# Invert Large Hash Table in Cpp or other fast language

Tags: c++, hashmap

I am looking for efficient C++ (or other fast) to invert a huge hash table.

The number of hash keys is on the order of 200,000,000;  and the number of possible elements in each hash key is of the order of 100,000.

I'd like to know what'd be a good way to (efficiently) invert such table such that now the elements are the keys and the keys are the elements.

Right now I have the data in my hard drive stored in a file called hash_file.txt.  The file looks like:

```
>1
T1
T3
T4
T100
>2
T4
T77
T9980
etc.
```

Where, >1,...,>200,000,000 are all the possible keys of the original hash table;
and T1,...,T100000 are all the possible elements for each key.
Note: The hash table is quite sparse with no more of a few hundred elements per key.

The output, inverted hash table would look like this in this example:

```
>T1
1
>T3
1
>T100
1
>T4
1
2
>T77
2
>T9980
2
```

I tried some naive code and took forever, and run out of mem, so I am looking for good suggestions to start with.

Comment: can you show your attempted code?

Comment: @Lie no point, and embarassing, is completely inefficient, I basically tried storing everything into a 200,000 by 200,000,000 matrix and run of mem.  I am looking first to know if it's possible to do such inversion of such huge hash table in good time and recs on how to do it, no need to provide full code

Comment: Are these keys contiguous?  That is - does every key from 1 to 200,000,000 have one or more Tn elements associated with it, and/or Tx exist for every x between 1 and ~100,000?  (If so, your outer data structures should be arrays/vectors not hash tables - perhaps vectors of vectors or sets).

Comment: @Dnaiel: you might be surprised at how people can spot and solve issues with implementations, and anyway - any attempt however inefficient is another form of documentation of the problem and intended solution... Lie's request is reasonable.

Comment: @TonyD thanks. it's like in the example.  Each key from 1 to 200,000,000 have one or more Tn elements, normally on the order of at most a 100 or so per key.

Comment: @TonyD, in general i agree but showing a code that creates a matrix, gets out of mem, and then (to invert the hash table) goes on the order of 200,000*200,000,000 sounds very unuseful, I mean if there is a pseudocode solution i'd be happy to code it as well.  It's just that the simplest solution is super simple but it happens to be completely impractical.

Comment: @Dnaiel: thanks for the clarification.  (re "it's like in the example" - we see >1 and >2 in the example: not enough data points to infer from, and "are all the *possible* keys" gently implies they're not necessarily all in use).  Could you give us some kind of histogram of how many N keys map to any given number of TN values (the first few frequencies are most important... 1, 2, 3)?  Are you building 64-bit, and with how much RAM?

Comment: @TonyD thanks.  I don't have the histogram because I haven't been able to invert the data.  However, I expect that on average each TN value will have around 100 keys (i.e., Tk:{2,4,...,900} with one hundred elements inside).  I also expect many Tks to have very few keys (0,1,2,3 quite common), and some long tail with some Tks having many many keys.  Yes, I have 64-bit, 40 Gb Ram

Comment: Your question title states that you want to load the whole thing into memory, but is that actually a requirement? Or do you just want to invert the hash as stated and you don't really care how it's done?

Comment: @harmic, good point, not real need to store it in mem as long as it can be done in some smart efficient way, I changed the tile and the question to de-impose such constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty simply approach; worth a try (remember to build with optimisation enabled, but preferably not disabling assert ;-)).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    char c;
    int n;
    int key = -1;
    const int max_t = 100000;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(max_t + 1);
    while (std::cin >> c >> n)
        if (c == '>')
            key = n;
        else
        {
            assert(c == 'T');
            assert(key != -1);
            assert(0 <= n && n < v.size());
            v[n].push_back(key);
        }
    assert(std::cin.eof());
    for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (v[i].empty()) continue;
        std::cout << ">T" << i << '\n';
        for (int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); ++j)
             std::cout << v[i][j] << '\n';
    }
}
```

(the output order is numeric not lexicographical like in your question... if you cared you could look for / write an algorithm to iterate in "i" in such a way mirroring lexicographical ordering)

Comment: thanks a lot.  Still thinking the last thing i need but this helps me a lot

Comment: @Dnaiel: sorry - you lost me there - what do you mean about "the last thing i need"?  I didn't notice another requirement in the question....

Comment: @Dnaiel Out of curiousity - can you tell me roughly how long it took to run?

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is framed around using an in-memory hash to invert the relationship of these items, as per the comments all you really want to do is get the output and the means is not important.

Since the amount of data you are working with, loading it all into memory is probably not going to be practical no matter what data structure you choose. So you are going to need some method that includes only a part of the data into memory at once.

I would be inclined to use a database for a task like this. Create a table which has two columns - the existing 'key' column, and the 'T' value column. Put an index on the value column. Then run a query which gives you the output you want.

Here is an example I knocked up using Postgresql:

```
create table bigmap (
  key integer,
  value text
);

create index on bigmap(value);

insert into bigmap(key,value) values (1, 'T1');
insert into bigmap(key,value) values (1, 'T3');
insert into bigmap(key,value) values (1, 'T4');
insert into bigmap(key,value) values (1, 'T100');
insert into bigmap(key,value) values (2, 'T4');
insert into bigmap(key,value) values (2, 'T77');
insert into bigmap(key,value) values (2, 'T9980');

select value,key from bigmap order by value,key;

 value | key
-------+-----
 T1    |   1
 T100  |   1
 T3    |   1
 T4    |   1
 T4    |   2
 T77   |   2
 T9980 |   2
(7 rows)
```

Populating the database from your input file should be relatively trivial. You could write a program in C++ to do this, but depending on how often you want to do it, you might be better off to use eg. perl

The advantage of using a database is that they already have efficient routines for sorting and indexing such data, and also have built in handling for preparing large query results using temporary files if the amount of memory available is not sufficient.

Also, if you want to find all the keys for a specific T-Value, it's easy:

```
select value,key from bigmap where value='T100';
 value | key
-------+-----
 T100  |   1
(1 row)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this looks like what I am looking for.  I'll try it out and let you know.