# Get next number from range in lexicographical order (without container of all stringifications)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic, iterator

> **How have/would you design an function that on each call returns the next value in a nominated numeric range *in lexicographical order of string representation*...?**

**Example**: range 8..203 --> 10, 100..109, 11, 110..119, 12, 120..129, 13, 130..139, ..., 19, 190..199, 20, 200..203, 30..99.

**Constraints**: indices 0..~INT_MAX, fixed space, O(range-length) performance, preferably "lazy" so if you stop iterating mid way you haven't wasted processing effort.  Please *don't post brute force "solutions"* iterating numerically while generating strings that are then sorted.

**Utility**: if you're generating data that ultimately needs to be lexicographically presented or processed, a lexicographical series promises lazy generation as needed, reduces memory requirements and eliminates a sort.

**Background**: when answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695374/invert-large-hash-table-in-cpp-or-other-fast-language/20695908?noredirect=1#comment30997133_20695908) today, my solution gave output in numeric order (i.e. 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), not lexicographical order (10, 11, 12, 8, 8) as illustrated in the question.  I imagined it would be easy to write or find a solution, but my Google-foo let me down and it was trickier than I expected, so I figured I'd collect/contribute here....

(Tagged C++ as it's my main language and I'm personally particularly interested in C++ solutions, but anything's welcome)

Somebody voted to close this because I either didn't demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved (hmmmm!?! ;-P), or an attempted solution.  **My solution is posted as an answer** as I'm happy for it to be commented on and regailed in the brutal winds of Stack Overflow wisdom.... O_o

Comment: You may not like it but a good way would be to first form an array of [11..1001] and then sort it as per custom compare function.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: that's ok if you're memory/performance requirements allow it, but the question as stated clearly focuses on looking for solutions that don't populate and sort extra data structures.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal, that wouldn't work so well with `[0, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a mess, so I'm curious to see how other people tackle it.  There are so many edge cases explicitly handled in the increment operator!

For range `low` to `high`:

- 0 is followed by 1
- numbers shorter than `high` are always followed by 0-appended versions (e.g. 12->120)
- numbers other than `high` that end in 0-8 are followed by the next integer
- when `low` has as many digits as `high`, you finish after `high` (return sentinel `high + 1`)

  - otherwise you finish at a number `999...` with one less digit than `high`
- other numbers ending in 9(s) have the part before the trailing 9s incremented, but if that results in trailing 0s they're removed providing the number's still more than `low`

```
template <typename T>
std::string str(const T& t)
{
    std::ostringstream oss; oss << t; return oss.str();
}

template <typename T>
class Lex_Counter
{
  public:
    typedef T value_type;

    Lex_Counter(T from, T to, T first = -1)
      : from_(from), to_(to),
        min_size_(str(from).size()), max_size_(str(to).size()),
        n_(first != -1 ? first : get_first()),
        max_unit_(pow(10, max_size_ - 1)), min_unit_(pow(10, min_size_ - 1))
    { }

    operator T() { return n_; }

    T& operator++()
    {
        if (n_ == 0)
            return n_ = 1;
        if (n_ < max_unit_ && n_ * 10 <= to_)
            return n_ = n_ * 10; // e.g. 10 -> 100, 89 -> 890
        if (n_ % 10 < 9 && n_ + 1 <= to_)
            return ++n_;         // e.g. 108 -> 109
        if (min_size_ == max_size_
            ? n_ == to_
            : (n_ == max_unit_ - 1 && to_ < 10 * max_unit_ - 10 || // 99/989
               n_ == to_ && to_ >= 10 * max_unit_ - 10))   // eg. 993
            return n_ = to_ + 1;

        // increment the right-most non-9 digit
        // note: all-9s case handled above (n_ == max_unit_ - 1 etc.)
        // e.g. 109 -> 11, 19 -> 2, 239999->24, 2999->3

        // comments below explain 230099 -> 230100

        // search from the right until we have exactly non-9 digit
        for (int k = 100; ; k *= 10)
            if (n_ % k != k - 1)
            {
                int l = k / 10; // n_ 230099, k 1000, l 100
                int r = ((n_ / l) + 1) * l; // 230100
                if (r > to_ && r / 10 < from_)
                    return n_ = from_; // e.g. from_ 8, r 20...
                while (r / 10 >= from_ && r % 10 == 0)
                    r /= 10; // e.g. 230100 -> 2301
                return n_ = r <= from_ ? from_ : r;
            }
        assert(false);
    }

  private:
    T get_first() const
    {
        if (min_size_ == max_size_ ||
            from_ / min_unit_ < 2 && from_ % min_unit_ == 0)
            return from_;

        // can "fall" from e.g. 321 to 1000
        return min_unit_ * 10;
    }
    T pow(T n, int exp)
        { return exp == 0 ? 1 : exp == 1 ? n : 10 * pow(n, exp - 1); }
    T from_, to_;
    size_t min_size_, max_size_;
    T n_;
    T max_unit_, min_unit_;
};
```

### Performance numbers

I can count from 0 to 1 billion in under a second on a standard Intel machine / single threaded, MS compiler at -O2.

The same machine / harness running my attempt at Shahbaz's solution - below - takes over 3.5 second to count to 100,000.  Maybe the `std::set` isn't a good heap/heap-substitute, or there's a better way to use it?  Any optimisation suggestions welcome.

```
template <typename T>
struct Shahbaz
{
    std::set<std::string> s;
    Shahbaz(T from, T to)
      : to_(to)
    {
        s.insert(str(from));
        for (int n = 10; n < to_; n *= 10)
            if (n > from) s.insert(str(n));
        n_ = atoi(s.begin()->c_str());
    }

    operator T() const { return n_; }

    Shahbaz& operator++()
    {
        if (s.empty())
            n_ = to_ + 1;
        else
        {
            s.erase(s.begin());
            if (n_ + 1 <= to_)
            {
                s.insert(str(n_ + 1));
                n_ = atoi(s.begin()->c_str());
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }

  private:
    T n_, to_;
};
```

Perf code for reference...

```
void perf()
{
    DWORD start = GetTickCount();
    int to = 1000 *1000;
    // Lex_Counter<int> counter(0, to);
    Shahbaz<int> counter(0, to);

    while (counter <= to)
        ++counter;
    DWORD elapsed = GetTickCount() - start;
    std::cout << '~' << elapsed << "ms\n";
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that your `for (int k = 100; ; k *= 10)` is multiplying the order of the algorithm by `O(log N)`?

Comment: @Shahbaz: ummm... no... still haven't got my head around that.  Trying to get a feel for it... worst case with a range 0 to 1 billion, there'd be 10,000,000 values ending in 9X triggering a second iteration, then 1,000,000 with yet another iteration, etc., so 11,111,111 extra operations - about 1.1% of N?  Not the log(N) implied 900% times slower.  I think the the crucial thing here is that not every number enters the loop - ending with consecutive 9s.  Does that all ring true?  I think this processing is much lighter than stringification for heap insertion too.

Comment: @Shahbaz: edited in some real world performance figures - maybe not entirely valid - but somewhere to start discussions if you're also interested to see what can be milked out of solutions.

Comment: Right, I had assumed you look at all the digits. I have been careless with that. Regardless your implementation, how about using `std::priority_queue` instead? That is a heap, while a `std::set` is a balanced binary tree.

Comment: Furthermore, I wouldn't store the values as `std::string`.  That's very very inefficient. Simple `unsigned int` would do (if the range is below a billion).

Comment: Ok, I implemented it myself and you're right. My version is not performant for ranges bigger than tens of millions. Looking at cachegrind's output (for my implementation), it seems like most of the time is spent in copying strings. I'm not going to pursue this anymore, but you could try compiling with C++11 and using move constructor to avoid copies (also increment the string manually instead of converting to int and back (which creates (`new`s) another string). Perhaps that could be better, removing all the copies that C++ loves to create!

Answer (score 3):

This is actually quite easy. First an observation:

**Theorem**: if two numbers `x` and `y` such that `x < y` are in the series and these numbers have the same number of digits, then `x` comes before `y`.

**Proof**: let's view digits of `x` as `xn..x0` and digits of `y` as `yn...y0`.  Let's take the left most digit that these two differ in, assumed to be at index `i`. Therefore, we have:

```
y = yn...yiy(i-1)...y0
x = yn...yix(i-1)...x0
```

since all digits from `n` to `i` are the same in both numbers. If `x < y`, then mathematically:

```
x(i-1) < y(i-1)
```

Lexicographically, if the digit `x(i-1)` is smaller than the digit `y(i-1)`, then `x` comes before `y`.

---

This theorem means that in your specified range of `[a, b]`, you have numbers with different number of digits, but the ones that have the same number of digits are in their mathematical order.

Building on that, here's a simple algorithm. First, let's say `a` has `m` digits and `b` has `n` digits (`n >= m`)

```
1. create a heap with lexicographical order
2. initially, insert `a` and `10^i` for i in [n + 1, m]
3. while the heap is not exhausted
3.1. remove and yield the top of the heap (`next`) as next result
3.2. if `next + 1` is still in range `[a, b]` (and doesn't increase in digits), insert it in heap
```

Notes:

- In step 2, you are inserting the starting numbers of each series of numbers that have the same number of digits.
- To change to a function that returns a number on each call, step 3.1 should be changed to store the state of the algorithm and resume on next call. Pretty standard.
- Step 3.2 is the part that exploits the above theorem and keeps only the next number in mathematical order in the heap.

Assuming `N = b - a`, The extra space used by this algorithm is `O(log N)` and it's time complexity is `O(N * log log N)`.

Comment: Doesn't "create a heap with lexicographical order" amount to the brute force approach I mentioned in the "Constraints" section of the question?

Comment: @TonyD, I wouldn't call it brute force. Brute force would be for example generating all possible series and choosing the correct one. This is certainly not as bad. Another reason why I wouldn't call it brute force is that it's using a property of the system to go in the right direction with small (`O(logN)` space, `O(log log N)` time) overhead.

Comment: @TonyD, also, any algorithm that looks at the digits directly wouldn't be any better than `O(N log N)` since it looks at `log N` digits at each step. Note that I'm assuming hardware operations to be `O(1)` (such as comparison and summation). Otherwise, there is a lot of `log N` scattered everywhere!

Comment: @Shahbaz Nice Idea! I think after getting a number you should also delete the previous number inserted from the heap. Else it will accumulate. Am i right?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal, I had assumed yielding the top of the heap would imply removing it also, but I'll clarify it.

Comment: @Shahbaz: sorry - took me a while to get my head around it. That's really nice, and as you say has quite low overheads for insertion sorting and space.  Wish I'd thought of that!  Cheers.

Comment: @TonyD, no problem! By the way, inserting in a heap is more efficient than inserting in an array (as insertion sort would do). If there are `M` elements, inserting in a sorted array costs `O(M)` while in a heap it costs `O(log M)`. The heap in the solution has `log N` elements, and hence the `log log N` term in the analysis.

Comment: For clarity you may also want to add the check that if next + 1 is not a power of 10, only then insert.

Comment: @Shahbaz: yes... calling it an insertion sort was sloppy of me.  Sorting on insertion.  From what I can gather, for this purpose at least the heap is much like a `std::set<>` in C++ (which is a balanced binary tree), but I should read up on heaps.  Appreciate the O(log log N).  Does stringification of the values hit the big-O efficiency somewhere, or is that below the threshold for visible impact at high N?

Comment: I've got a hunch that an array indexed by width of number could use your insights re ordering and blitz both our current code - e.g. 18-2037 range initialises array [18, 100, 1000] then have to work out which one to use/increment next - just check right against left *10 until > - will think/code more later.

Comment: @TonyD, one thing I have over looked is comparing the numbers lexicographically. That would change the `log log N` back to `log N`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt, in Python:

```
import math

#iterates through all numbers between start and end, that start with `cur`'s digits
def lex(start, end, cur=0):
    if cur > end:
        return
    if cur >= start:
        yield cur
    for i in range(0,10):
        #add 0-9 to the right of the current number
        next_cur = cur * 10 + i
        if next_cur == 0: 
            #we already yielded 0, no need to do it again
            continue
        for ret in lex(start, end, next_cur):
            yield ret

print list(lex(8, 203))
```

Result:

```
[10, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 11, 110, 111, 112, 113, 
114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 12, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 
129, 13, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 14, 140, 141, 142, 
143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 15, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 
158, 159, 16, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 17, 170, 171, 
172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 18, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 
187, 188, 189, 19, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 20, 200, 
201, 202, 203, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 
37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 
57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
77, 78, 79, 8, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 9, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 
96, 97, 98, 99]
```

This uses O(log(end)) stack space, which is bounded by INT_MAX, so it won't go any deeper than five calls for your typical 16 bit int. It runs in O(end) time, since it has to iterate through numbers smaller than `start` before it can begin yielding valid numbers. This can be considerably worse than O(end-start) if `start` and `end` are large and close together.

Iterating through `lex(0, 1000000)` takes about six seconds on my machine, so it appears to be slower than Tony's method but faster than Shahbaz's. Of course, it's challenging to make a direct comparison since I'm using a different language.

Comment: Elegant simplicity to the code, and performs nicely too!  I wish C++ had support for coroutines (yield et al) in the Standard.  Some implementations around but hackish and poorly supported.  I use python at work though, so extra curious to see your code.  I can kind of grope mentally at how to jump more directly to generation from start, but it'd be a shame to muddy it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Some Java code (deriving C++ code from this should be trivial), very similar to Kevin's Python solution:

```java
public static void generateLexicographical(int lower, int upper)
{
   for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
      generateLexicographical(lower, upper, i);
}

private static void generateLexicographical(int lower, int upper, int current)
{
   if (lower <= current && current <= upper)
      System.out.println(current);

   if (current > upper)
      return;

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      generateLexicographical(lower, upper, 10*current + i);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   generateLexicographical(11, 1001);
}
```

The order of the if-statements are not important, and one can be made an `else` of the other, but changing them in any way strangely enough makes it take about 20% longer.

This just starts with each number from 1 to 10, then recursively appends each possible number from 0 to 10 to that number, until we get a number bigger than the upper limit.

It similarly uses `O(log upper)` space (every digit requires a stack frame) and `O(upper)` time (we go from `1` to `upper`).

I/O is obviously the most time-consuming part here. If that is removed and replaced by just incrementing a variable, `generateLexicographical(0, 100_000_000);` takes about 4 seconds, but by no means taken from a proper benchmark.

Comment: Hi Dukeling.  Memory use is still tiny for the ranges that can be handled in a reasonable timeframe.  Interesting to contrast recursion with and without "yield" though - I guess Java and C++ both lack it?  Without, it's a bit more restrictive in use - you can't keep multiple "iterator" objects tracking arbitrary ranges and get the next numbers however you like unless you give them a thread each and pay for synchronisation - but most of the time it'd serve just fine.  Cheers.